# Create XMLElement from partial XML

Tags: xml, vb.net

first off apologies I have never coded with XML constructs in .NET so I hope the question makes sense.

Let me start by defining my XML:

```html
<Msg>
  <Routing>
    ...
    ...
    ...
  </Routing>
  
  <PayLoad>
    
    <Information>
      <elem1>...</elem1>
      <elem2>...</elem2>
      ..
      ..
    </Information>
    
    <History>
      <hist1>...</hist1>
      <hist2>...</hist2>
    </History>
    
  </PayLoad>
  
</Msg>
```

I get this entire XML as a String.

I need to now call another function which takes a custom class as an argument. The custom class has 2 properties: 1 is another custom class which contains the routing information and the other is of type System.Xml.XmlElement. The signature is something like this:

```
public class Message
    Public header as HeaderInfo
    Public payload as System.Xml.XmlElement
End Class
```

In essence, I need to convert everything within the `<PayLoad>` tags to a type System.Xml.XmlElement, maintaining the XML structure under PayLoad (I was able to generate the HeaderInfo class)

The XML schema is fixed and it will always have the same elements in it.

Any ideas on how to do this? 
I'm using VB.NET on .NET 3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `XmlDocument` to get the `<Payload>` element as `XmlElement` without reparsing, for example :

```
Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
doc.LoadXml("Your XML string goes here")
Dim payload As XmlElement = DirectCast(doc.SelectSingleNode("//Payload"), XmlElement)
```

Comment: this looks like exactly what I need.. is there some way just to check the entire XML inside the payload variable? Something to dump it into a String which I can easily output?

Comment: `payload.OuterXml` is what you're looking for

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim xMsg as XElement = XElement.Parse("<Msg><Routing>...</Routing><PayLoad><Information><elem1>...</elem1></Information><History><hist1>...</hist1></History></PayLoad></Msg>")
Dim xPayLoad as XElement = xMsg...<PayLoad> 'Get PayLoad descendants (with sneaky VB syntax)
```

If you could change `Message.payload` from `XmlElement` to `XElement` you are done here. If not you have to convert it:

```
Dim xmlDoc = new XmlDocument()
xmlDoc.Load(xPayLoad.CreateReader())  
Message.payload = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.B, unfortunately I have no control over the input and output, I'm working in the "middleware" part so I need to do the converstion

Comment: The last 3 rows of my post should do the conversion

Answer (score 0):

A small change to Message

```
Public Class Message
    Public header As HeaderInfo
    Public payload As XElement
End Class
```

and then some code to convert a string to XML.

```
    Dim s As String = "<Msg>  <Routing></Routing>  <PayLoad>    <Information>      <elem1>...</elem1>      <elem2>...</elem2>    </Information>    <History>      <hist1>...</hist1>      <hist2>...</hist2>    </History>  </PayLoad></Msg>"

    Dim someMessage As New Message
    someMessage.payload = XElement.Parse(s)
```

One question, why is the XML a string in the first place?

Comment: Thanks dbasnett, unfortunately I have no control over the input and output, I'm working in the "middleware" part so I need to do the converstion